# Java exporting images with runnable jar getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("path") returns null

Tags: java

I am trying to export an image inside my runnable jar. After some research i have come across this method:

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("image path"));
```

After following several response and looking at the API, i have attempted this myself. My current directory set up is as follows:

[image]

This is my code:

```
cherryImg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/res/cherry.png"));
```

which is being called from the Snake.java source file.

This is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at cje.chris.edwards.snake.game.Snake.<init>(Snake.java:51)
    at cje.chris.edwards.snake.game.Snake.main(Snake.java:156)
```

`Snake.java:51` is the line of code posted above. I understand this is because it cannot find the resource, what am i doing wrong? I have added the res folder to my build path.

I have also tried:

```
cherryImg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/cherry.png"));
```

This produces the same error message.

**Answer:**

```
cherryImg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("cherry.png"));
```

Thanks.

Comment: is the file actually in the `.jar`? you don't specify how you are creating the `.jar`, it probably isn't even in there.

Comment: The thread you linked me to had the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the leading "/"

```
"/res/cherry.png"
```

Will make it an absolute path (from your root of your drive) not a relative path from your starting from the root of your jar

Making it `"res/cherry.png"` should work

Comment: Nope. I tried that before posting, the same error persists.